# Can I list multiple sitemaps inside one sitemap.xml and specify that in my robots.txt?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

The sitemap engine I'm using generates a strange `sitemap.xml`. I need to add *blog* and *shop* sitemaps for those URLs too.

Now in *robots.txt* I specify this path `https://example.com/sitemap-shop.xml`, but I want `https:///example.com/sitemap-blog.xml` to be indexed by Google too. Actually, I have this in `https://example.com/sitemap.xml`, where all sitemaps are listed.

If I specify in my *robots.txt* `https:///example.com/sitemap.xml`, can Google see the links for the blog and shop sitemaps at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main `sitemap.xml` group multiple sitemap files which is a practice part of the [sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index).

> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should then list each Sitemap
>   file in a Sitemap index file.

Every SE capable of reading sitemaps should be able to understand it.

You can also add the three sitemap files in [Google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list) to be sure, but sending the main `sitemap.xml` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

most ecommerce websites use this approach because they have large number of products classified by catagories. This approach help to maintain large sitemap.
The main sitemap should contain list of other sitemaps.
It is always better to include sitemap urls in robots.txt , so crawlers could pick sitemap easily.
Our sitemap should contain unique urls.
filetype should be xml.